# App not showing on portrait mode in Galaxy m pro

Tags: android, android-orientation

i have created an application which is only work on potrait mode, Samsung screening review give a issue application work on landspace mode on Mid-end Galaxy (LQVGA), They also give video for same to identify, i found they are right, My app show in landscape mode for that device, but i am not able to find the reason, Why this is happen, because except that device my app work fine on all device, i also find device name is Galaxy M pro , i am attaching file screen shot of issue, please suggest me any way to resolve this issue, i already added  android:screenOrientation="portrait" that in all activity of manifest.xml file

[image]

Comment: Check your device orientation settings.You must have locked your device in landscape mode.